# Invalid Identifier PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to accept three different inputs: course_no, depart, and enrollment. 
But I am getting this error:

```
old   4:  select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where dept = &depart;
new   4:  select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where dept = csce;
select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where code = csce;
                                                   *

ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 56:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CSCE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

My dept class has a code column of type char(4), so I do not know why it is an invalid identifier.
Here is what I have:

```
ACCEPT course_no number PROMPT "Enter course_no ";
ACCEPT Depart PROMPT "Enter Dept ";
ACCEPT Enrollment number PROMPT "Enter Enrollment ";

DECLARE

BEGIN
   select count(*) into Department from dept where code = &depart;

END;
/
```

Comment: Why are you putting an `&` in there? In `&depart` ?

Comment: @bytepusher I deleted it and it is still giving me the same error. But this time it is:  PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DEPART": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as this :

```
   select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where dept = '&depart'; -- enter csce whenever prompts
```

Use quotations, since `code` is of type char. Always prefer using bind variable instead of literal (more secure anti-injection & your sql not needn't to be parsed again and again)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use string literal:

```
select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where dept = csce;
-- =>
select count(*) into DeptFound from dept where dept = 'csce';  
                                               -- case-sensitive
```